# Is there a tool that creates xsl:fo from xsl so it will be the same output?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Is there any tool that takes xsl file and converting it to the same xsl:fo ?
I have html file that is converted from xsl+xsl and now I like to take the xsl and to create xsl:fo 
For fop and I really don’t want to write xsl:fo now

Answer (score 0):

You need a transformation something fop understands, and that is xsl:fo only, or to put it differntly fop cannot print HTML.

Look into HTML to PDF conversion that, IMHO, is more suited for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[AntennaHouse](http://www.antennahouse.com/) has a set of stylesheets to convert XHTML to XSL-FO:

[**http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/XSLsample.htm#HTMLtoFO**](http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/XSLsample.htm#HTMLtoFO)

Comment: Then adjusting your xhtml would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Ecrion](http://www.ecrion.com) engine; it should work with HTML (not well formed) and XHTML; in both cases use InputFormat.HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RenderX Products](http://www.renderx.com/tools/index.html) , which can format XSL/XSL+XML to HTML, PDF, PS ... and so.

Regards, Greg